# awk regular expression in RS

Tags: regex, bash, awk

My file is like this

```
A0010 A R G 222
ALBXXXXXLE DRIVE - NO N1 Y 2 C 1 0
A R G BOBBY BEARD 1 NC N N 0 0.00
 AERXXXX 0.00
 NC 22211 

A0013 

A & A SERVICE CENTER P O BOX 113 - NO N1 Y 2 C 1 0

A & A SERVICE CENTER 1 NC N Y 0 0.00

HARRELLSVILLE 0.00
 NC 27942 

A0016 A HOME GARDEN SHOP 111 E MAIN STREET 111-111-1110 NO N1 Y 2 U 1 0
 HOME GARDEN SHOP PAM 1 NC N Y 0 0.00
 AERBDER 0.00
 NC 24520 

A0039 XXXXXXX HILL APTS. P.O. BOX 604 222-7111 NO N1 Y 2 U 1 0
 XXXXXXX HILL APTS. TXXXMAN MORRIS 1 NC Y Y 0 0.00
 AERBDER 0.00
 NC 27510
```

I want to separate each record using the first column A0010, A0013, A0016, A0039 and load into database. I tried using awk, but it took only the first matching as record separate.

```
cat temp1 | gawk 'BEGIN {RS="^[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]";} {print NR,"and RT=" RT}' | sed -e 's/ \+/ /g'
```

o/p

```
1 and RT=A0010

2 and RT=
```

It is not taking the 2nd match. Please help

Comment: could you edit your post and indent your input file so that we know *exactly* how it looks like?

Comment: `gawk -v RS="[A-Z][0-9]{4}" '{print NR,"and RT=" RT}' temp1` should do it.

Comment: @fedorqui that is the exact content of the file

Comment: @anubhava - shows wrong results when the pattern is in the middle of the content

Comment: @KarthikAppigatla: You can try: `gawk -v RS="\n[A-Z][0-9]{4}" '{print NR,"and RT=" RT " and $0=" $0}' file`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your awk command with the following:

```
cat temp1 | awk 'BEGIN {RS="[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]";} {print NR,"and RT=" RT}'
```

The `^` is causing your problem.

**Edit (based on the comments):**

If the pattern occurs at the beginning and in the middle of lines:

```
 grep -E "^[A-Z][0-9]{3}" temp1 | gawk 'BEGIN {RS="[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]";} {print NR,"and RT=" RT}'
```

Comment: You should not use  `cat` with program that can read data itself.  `awk 'code' temp1`

Comment: I already tried that and it works. But there are similar patterns in the middle of the line also. I have put only few lines of my file. Is there any way to replace ^

Comment: Do you want to only get the ones which are at the beginning of lines?

Comment: yes Aman. I tried this...but is there a better solution than using \n because first line will be missed by using \n
    
 `cat temp1 | gawk 'BEGIN {RS="\n[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]";} {print NR,"and RT=" RT}'  | sed -e 's/ \+/ /g'`
1 and RT=
A0013
2 and RT=
A0016
3 and RT=
A0039

Comment: My solution is not pretty and I am sure that there is an` awk` way, but you can use: `grep -E "^[A-Z][0-9]{3}" temp1 | gawk 'BEGIN {RS="[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]";} {print NR,"and RT=" RT}'`